Would having a pertinent, unique chat room title add to the site?
Gaming has "The Bridge", DBA has "The Heap", Sci-Fi has "Mos Eisley", and many other SE chat rooms have unique names.  As Ben has pointed out, it should be pertinent and an accurate statement about our focus.
Would anyone be amenable to, and perhaps have a suggestion for, a new chat room title?
I don't think it would work any magic in attracting new users to the site, but it could add a bit of novelty that might inspire someone to check us out.
Please add your own suggestions as an answer and/or vote for the ones you like

I would want it to at least be clearly related to the site's focus, not quite as silly/unrelated as The Bridge and some other room names.

@BenBrocka Absolutely, edited it a bit.

"Broca's Area" might work, hehe.

I think it is more important to first figure out what our site name will be... before worrying about what pun to make with our chat room.

@ArtemKaznatcheev Fair enough.  I had just kicked this around with Ben in chat and we figured we'd pop it up as a Meta question just to keep everyone in the loop.

@ChuckSherrington yeah, I actually saw it from chat.

Alternately, the chat room title is a lot easier to decide on and easier to change

The Axon Terminal
You know, a terminal, like a place we talk about axons?

The Left Hemisphere
(Chuck Sherrington gave me this idea, so I steal it without hesitation.)

I'll be sending my army of lawyers, don't worry ;)

Broca's Area


Brocka's Area would work, too, hehe

The Lab
Boring

Brain drain
(but has a quite negative connotation, I guess)

I think it has an ironic twist to it, hehe.  Within reason, just put your ideas out there and everyone can decide.

And another pun:
CerebRoom / Cereb-Room

The BAU

Medulla blaterare


Did you mean: blaterare  ?

@Ben I never did get around to learning Latin :)
